# VS2008 project with Entity Framework model results in "always dirty" compile

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, msbuild, dependencies

In VS 2008, I have a simple .csproj that contains an Entity Framework .edmx (V1) file.  Every time I build the project, the output DLL is updated, even though nothing has changed.  I have reproduced this in the simplest-possible project (containing one ordinary .cs file and one edmx model).  If I remove the edmx model and build repeatedly, the output assembly will not be touched.  If I add the edmx model and build repeatedly, the output assembly is modified each time.  This is a problem because the real project is a dependency of dozens of other projects and it is wreaking havoc with what times when working in higher layers of the application.  Is this a known problem?  Any way to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found this little gem on a [Microsoft EF blog:](http://blogs.msdn.com/craigl/archive/2010/03/26/new-entity-designer-features-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

> Incremental Build We used to re-deploy
>   EDMX files (if any of the files were
>   set to produced embedded output
>   resources) regardless of whether
>   anything had changed in the model.
>   This unnecessarily initiated other
>   build actions, and for some large
>   projects, these extra build actions
>   could take some time. In VS 2010, we
>   updated our EntityDeploy build task to
>   only deploy when the model has
>   changed.

At least it's fixed in EF4...